# Why is my Python reading only csv files and not xlsx files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlrd

My Python is not reading xlsx (excel) files, but reading csv only. I have all the updated Python version (39), pip, xlrd, pandas. Still no result. Please help!

*Already did: pip install xlrd, shows requirement already fulfilled.*

**INPUT:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

df= pd.read_excel("Test file 1.xlsx" , "A")
df

**ERROR:**

```
    err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
```

**AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'**

Comment: From [here](https://pypi.org/project/excelrd/): `xlrd` will not work at Python 3.9 or newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to install xlrd. `pip install xlrd`